# Php Mysql ignore empty columns in echo

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic display php table for images however some of the columns in the table are empty.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2
    WHERE bid=$bid
    AND fhid=$fhid
    ") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table align='center'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { 
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo '<a href="'.$row['photo1'].'"target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['thumb1'].'" width="180" height="250" alt="'.$row['name'].' '.$row['alttext'].'"/></a>';
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo '<a href="'.$row['photo16'].'"target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['thumb16'].'"width="180" height="250"alt="'.$row['name'].' '.$row['alttext'].'"/></a>';
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo '<a href="'.$row['photo2'].'"target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['thumb2'].'" width="180" height="250"alt="'.$row['name'].' '.$row['alttext'].'"/></a>';
    echo "</td></tr>";
} 
echo "</table>";
```

If for example the row with photo16 was empty in the db table how can I change this script to skip the image without showing a missing image on the page and carry on to photo2.

I have checked all around and had no luck with NULL as it stops displaying the whole row. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First **stop** using deprected `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared Statements. Second you have to ceck if the file exist and then decide if you create the link or not

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if isset the var you need  to controll ($row['photo16'])

```
    if (isset($row['photo16']) && strlen($row['photo16']) > 0) {
       echo '<a href="'.$row['photo16'].'"target="_blank">
               <img src="'.$row['thumb16'].'"width="180" height="250"alt="'.
                     $row['name'].' '.$row['alttext'].'"/></a>';
    }
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard  . your suggestion is correct but (if i understand correcly) seems that the question is related to a single image and not to all the row ... could be i'm wrong .

Comment: I thought about it more and it seems the OP is talking about skipping a column, not a row. You'd have to loop through the columns *inside* the `while` loop to achieve what the OP is after.

Comment: He is speaking about  skip photo16 but show photo2 .. is for this  .. i have proposed  this answer ..  should be better ask to the OP  ..  ..

Comment: OP says what s/he wants in the title of the post. And here, *"If for example the row with photo16 was empty in the db table how can I change this script to skip the image without showing a missing image on the page and carry on"* photo16 is just an example.

Comment: the OP in question body say "If for example the row with photo16 was empty in the db table how can I change this script to skip the image without showing a missing image on the page and carry on to photo2."

Comment: Note the words ***"for example"***

Comment: You can provide  youe answer  and let to the user the choice ..

Comment: I was just trying to help you out.

Comment: I   thanks  you very much  ...but the answer i provided   is based  on what  i have understand .. could be i fail

Comment: Thankyou "scaisEdge" have just tried it and it works perfect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add condition inside the while cycle if row is not empty. Something like this:

```
if(!empty($row)){
 echo "<table align='center'>";
 echo "<tr><td>";
 echo '<a href="'.$row['photo1'].'"target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['thumb1'].'" width="180" height="250" alt="'.$row['name'].' '.$row['alttext'].'"/></a>';
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo '<a href="'.$row['photo16'].'"target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['thumb16'].'"width="180" height="250"alt="'.$row['name'].' '.$row['alttext'].'"/></a>';
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo '<a href="'.$row['photo2'].'"target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['thumb2'].'" width="180" height="250"alt="'.$row['name'].' '.$row['alttext'].'"/></a>';
 echo "</td></tr>";
 }
```

Comment: The OP just wants to exclude the column where the empty value is.

Answer (score 0):

check with !empty() function

like below. If not empty then it will print

```
if (!empty($row['photo16'])  > 0) {
       echo '<a href="'.$row['photo16'].'"target="_blank">
               <img src="'.$row['thumb16'].'"width="180" height="250"alt="'.
                     $row['name'].' '.$row['alttext'].'"/></a>';
    }
```